# Splitting polyline by point using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects

I want to split gas pipe line by point and add two new feature and delete the old feature gas line.
I reach the code to split pipe line but does't work and stopped there 
 ISet newFeaturesSetTemp = featureEdit.SplitWithUpdate(pPoint);

```c#
  public override void OnMouseDown(int Button, int Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    IMxDocument mxdoc = m_application.Document as IMxDocument;
    IActiveView activeView = mxdoc.ActiveView;
    IPoint pPoint = activeView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(X, Y);
    IFeatureLayer pFlayer = null;
    IMap map = mxdoc.FocusMap;
    for (int i = 0; i < map.LayerCount - 2; i++)
    {
        ILayer layer = map.get_Layer(i);
        if (/*/layer is IFeatureLayer &&/*/ layer.Name == "Double_Endcap")
        { 
            pFlayer = layer as IFeatureLayer;
            break;
        }
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    IFeatureLayer flayer = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < map.LayerCount - 2; i++)
    {
        ILayer layer = map.get_Layer(i);
        if (/*layer is IFeatureLayer &&*/ layer.Name == "PePipe")
        {
            flayer = layer as IFeatureLayer;
            break;
        }
    }
    ITopologicalOperator topologicalOperator = pPoint as ITopologicalOperator;
    IGeometry geometry = topologicalOperator.Buffer(1);//(0.5);
    ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilterClass();
    spatialFilter.Geometry = geometry;
    spatialFilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
    //IFeatureSelection featureSelection = flayer as IFeatureSelection;//
    //featureSelection.SelectFeatures(spatialFilter, esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultNew, true);//
    IFeatureClass featureClass = flayer.FeatureClass;
    IFeatureCursor featurecursor = featureClass.Search(spatialFilter, false);
    IFeature feature = featurecursor.NextFeature();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int iOID = feature.OID;
    ////Split the feature. Use the IFeatureEdit::Split method which ensures
    ////the attributes are correctly dealt with.
    IFeatureEdit2 featureEdit = feature as IFeatureEdit2;
    ////Set to hold the new features that are created by the Split. 
    ISet newFeaturesSet = new SetClass();
    ISet newFeaturesSetTemp = featureEdit.SplitWithUpdate(pPoint);
    if (newFeaturesSetTemp != null)
    {
        newFeaturesSetTemp.Reset();
        for (int featureCount = 0; featureCount < newFeaturesSetTemp.Count; featureCount++)
        {
            IFeature newFeature = newFeaturesSetTemp.Next() as IFeature;
            if (newFeature.OID == iOID)
            {
                newFeaturesSet.Add(newFeature);
            }
        }
    }
    newFeaturesSet.Add(feature);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (feature == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Select Pipe");
    }
    else
    {
        IFeatureClass pFeaturecalass = pFlayer.FeatureClass as IFeatureClass;
        IDataset pDataset = pFeaturecalass as IDataset;
        IGeoDataset pGeoDataset = pFeaturecalass IGeoDataset;
        ISpatialReference sr = pGeoDataset.SpatialReference;
        sr.SetDomain(-1000000, 40000000, -1000000, 40000000);
        IWorkspace pWorkspace = pDataset.Workspace as IWorkspace;
        IWorkspaceEdit pWorkspaceEdit = pWorkspace as IWorkspaceEdit;
        pWorkspaceEdit.StartEditing(true);
        IFeature pNewFeature = pFeaturecalass .CreateFeature() as IFeature;
        pNewFeature.Shape = pPoint;
        pNewFeature.Shape.SpatialReference = sr;
        pNewFeature.Store();
        pWorkspaceEdit.StopEditOperation();
        pWorkspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
        activeView.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have this tagged [tag:qgis] but I am confident that you are using [tag:arcobjects] so I am replacing it with that.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Your point pPoint is created but no spatial reference is a assigned to it, this will often cause errors, it should be set to activeView.ScreenDisplay.FocusMap.SpatialReference and then project it to flayer.SpatialReference provided neither is of type UnknownSpatialReference. Try that and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time actually your answer is correct and is now operating successfully Thank you very much

Comment: That's great news Ahmed. I had a similar problem a few years ago and it came back to creating a new point but not giving it a spatial reference so I thought this could be the same. If you like you could answer your own question with just the edited section and an explanation - earn yourself some reputation. I like your code and think that this deserves an answer to show future readers how to fix similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct code after add a SpatialReference to point thank you @Michael Miles-Stimson

```c#
 public override void OnMouseDown(int Button, int Shift, int X, int Y)
    {
        IMxDocument mxdoc = m_application.Document as IMxDocument;
        IActiveView activeView = mxdoc.ActiveView;
        IPoint pPoint = activeView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(X, Y);
        IFeatureLayer pFlayer = null;
        IMap map = mxdoc.FocusMap;
        for (int i = 0; i < map.LayerCount - 2; i++)
        {
            ILayer layer = map.get_Layer(i);
            if (/*/layer is IFeatureLayer &&/*/ layer.Name == "Double_Endcap")
            { 
                pFlayer = layer as IFeatureLayer;
                break;
            }
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        IFeatureLayer flayer = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < map.LayerCount - 2; i++)
        {
            ILayer layer = map.get_Layer(i);
            if (/*layer is IFeatureLayer &&*/ layer.Name == "PePipe")
            {
                flayer = layer as IFeatureLayer;
                break;
            }
        }
        ITopologicalOperator topologicalOperator = pPoint as ITopologicalOperator;
        IGeometry geometry = topologicalOperator.Buffer(1);//(0.5);
        ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilterClass();
        spatialFilter.Geometry = geometry;
        spatialFilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
        //IFeatureSelection featureSelection = flayer as IFeatureSelection;//
        //featureSelection.SelectFeatures(spatialFilter, esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultNew, true);//
        IFeatureClass featureClass = flayer.FeatureClass as IFeatureClass;
        IFeatureCursor featurecursor = featureClass.Search(spatialFilter, false);
        IFeature feature = featurecursor.NextFeature();
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        IGeoDataset geoDataset = featureClass as IGeoDataset;
        ISpatialReference spatialReference = geoDataset.SpatialReference;
        spatialReference.SetDomain(-1000000, 40000000, -1000000, 40000000);
        pPoint = mxdoc.ActivatedView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(X, Y);
        int iOID = feature.OID;
        ////Split the feature. Use the IFeatureEdit::Split method which ensures
        ////the attributes are correctly dealt with.
        IFeatureEdit2 featureEdit = feature as IFeatureEdit2;
        ////Set to hold the new features that are created by the Split. 
        ISet newFeaturesSet = new SetClass();
        ISet newFeaturesSetTemp = featureEdit.SplitWithUpdate(pPoint);
        if (newFeaturesSetTemp != null)
        {
            newFeaturesSetTemp.Reset();
            for (int featureCount = 0; featureCount < newFeaturesSetTemp.Count; featureCount++)
            {
                IFeature newFeature = newFeaturesSetTemp.Next() as IFeature;
                if (newFeature.OID == iOID)
                {
                    newFeaturesSet.Add(newFeature);
                }
            }
        }
        newFeaturesSet.Add(feature);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (feature == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select Pipe");
        }
        else
        {
            IFeatureClass pFeaturecalass = pFlayer.FeatureClass as IFeatureClass;
            IDataset pDataset = featureClass as IDataset;
            IGeoDataset pGeoDataset = pFeaturecalass as IGeoDataset;
            ISpatialReference sr = pGeoDataset.SpatialReference;
            sr.SetDomain(-1000000, 40000000, -1000000, 40000000);
            IWorkspace pWorkspace = pDataset.Workspace as IWorkspace;
            IWorkspaceEdit pWorkspaceEdit = pWorkspace as IWorkspaceEdit;
            pWorkspaceEdit.StartEditing(true);
            IFeature pNewFeature = pFeaturecalass.CreateFeature() as IFeature;
            pNewFeature.Shape = pPoint;
            pNewFeature.Shape.SpatialReference = sr;
            pNewFeature.Store();
            pWorkspaceEdit.StopEditOperation();
            pWorkspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
            activeView.Refresh();
        }
    }
```